# Escaping double quotes in expect script

Tags: perl, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$command = "SetBaseStationParam(\\\"PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT\\\",0);"
system (boa.exp $command);
```

boa.exp script will take this command login to a linux machine and executes the script.

```
# /Usr/bin/expect 
set timeout 5
set arg1 [lindex 0]
spawn ssh root@10.xx.xx.xx

expect "password:" 
send "pass\r"
expect "$" 

send "$arg1\r"
expect "$"
```

But this script is removing the first double quotes in the command and printing it as

output is

```
SetBaseStationParam(\PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT",0);
```

Expected output is

```
SetBaseStationParam("PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT",0);
```

Please let me know if there is any solution for this

Answer (score 6):

When you use double backslashes it escapes the backslash, so the proper way to escape a quote is `\"`.

However, a better solution is to use `qq()`. It can be used with a great variety of characters as delimiter, such as `|` for example:

```
$command = qq|SetBaseStationParam("PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT",0)|;
```

Or in your case, even use single quotes

```
$command = 'SetBaseStationParam("PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT",0)';
```

You should be aware that not using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Is a very bad idea indeed.

Comment: It didnt work even with qq or single quotes (').

Now the output which is with qq or single quotes
SetBaseStationParam(PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT,1)

Comment: Try using list form, e.g. `system(qw|boa.exp SetBaseStationParam("PDP_ACTIVATION_REJECT",0)|);` then the shell does the quoting itself.